# Theme Inspector "X-Ray"

Tags: theme-development, themes

I looked around and sadly didn't find anything answering this, and I'm almost 100% sure that it doesn't exist but I figured I'd ask this active community.

I work in a Rails environment as a Front-End Engineer, but I still do a fair amount of WP work on the side. In our Rails project we use a nifty gem called **xray-rails** (demo can be found on [github.com/brentd/xray-rails](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails)) and I was wondering if anyone used anything fun to help expose what template is calling something on a screen, this seems like it'd be very helpful in child themes.

Comment: It is a little hard to bring over "what template is calling something on a screen" into WP realm from your description. Which kind of information are you interested in precisely? Files loaded? Hooks fired? Template hierarchy?

Comment: The closes I have found is: https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-template-file-am-i-viewing/developers/